# Separate sessions of the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use python script to do some calculations in the backend. The proccess works as follows:

- I create a list of variables by clicking on some items in the app
- That list is sent to the python script and it sends back a json back
- Based on that json file i display a table
- Then the list of variables is ereased and I can do this again

But here is the problem, when I run this locally on c9.io, lets say I give the address of that c9.io to someone, then when that person is clicking on variables to add to that list, he adds them to the same list as I do. There are no separate lists for other people when using the app from different ip or something and therefore it gets confusing because when I send to python script I get json file with results i didnt want, but someone else did.

But then Im planning on hosting it on heroku and I wonder if it will be working differently, so when someone is using the app from there he gets his own list of the variables and it wont be shared by everyone who is using this at the same time as someone. Or is there a some way to do this specifically?

Here is the backend code for the app:
First this is the code for adding items to the list and here is the problem since anyone if doing it at the same time will be adding to the same list

```
var jsondata = ""
var thelist =[]
app.get("/show/:id", function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    thelist.push(id)
    console.log(thelist);
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Then the rest (so running the script and emptying the list)

```
app.get("/run", function(req, res) {
            var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');
            pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(thelist))
            pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
            jsondata += message
            });

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
            pyshell.end(function (err) {
             if (err){
               throw err;
                };
            console.log(jsondata);
            });

            thelist = []
});


app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    if (jsondata == "") {
        res.redirect('/')
    } else {
    //viewname can include or omit the filename extension
    res.render("data", {data: JSON.parse(jsondata)} )
    jsondata = ""}
});
```

So I think i need those two variables `jsondata` and `thelist` need to be somehow coded in a way that they are seprate for every unique user (as in accessing the app from different place, so the app would be run as a separate session for each user that accesses it (but also no need for registration) )

Comment: IP would work partly as some ISPs hand out new ones every day so you won't be able to access your own list then (and maybe someone else gets your IP / list the next day)

Comment: You shouldn't rely on app instance. If there should be data that is specific to particular user, use sessions or other ways to identify a user. You never want to identify a user by IP (unless you want to blacklist him). Why should `jsondata` be stored in a variable? There are databases for that.

Comment: Yea I was looking for something that works like session(i guess app instance is bad wording from me, let me change that). I dont need for that list to be kept forever, actually it should just be able to be kept for a short time when the user is accessing website. I know I could do this in database but then it would require users to register to use it and that is not the point of that app.